# sorting list with context

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list from which you want to create a sorted list, however my sorting criteria is a fairly complicated expression referencing other data structures. I can specify the expression as a lambda passed to the "key" parameter of sorted, but this lambda is ugly, and I'd rather use a named function. The complication is that unless I make the referenced data structures globals, I can't find a way to pass them from the caller of "sorted".

Any suggestion?

Comment: post your code please

Comment: It may be helpful to know that functions can be nested in Python. Try writing your key function inside the same function that is calling `sorted`.

Comment: Excellent point kevin!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to bind the values of the "global" data structures you want to use as your context to parameters of the `key` function, leaving you with a callable that takes a single positional parameter as required by `sorted`:

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> def key_func(foo, bar, baz):
    print foo, bar, baz


>>> key = partial(key_func, bar=1, baz=2)  # bind globals
>>> key(0)  # call with each item being sorted
0 1 2
```